# Why does action bar toggle on toolbar is not showing

Tags: android

I am trying to implement `NavigationView`. I have a `ToolBar` on which I want to add `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. I am not sure why it is not visible.

### DashboardActivity.java

```
public class DashboardActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityDashboardBinding activityDashboardBinding = setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        // setting the toolbar title
        setToolbarText(getString(R.string.home_screen_name));

        // initializing drawer layout and action bar toggle
        mDrawerLayout = activityDashboardBinding.drawer;
        mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.home_screen_open_drawer, R.string.home_screen_close_drawer) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank

                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);

        //calling sync state is necessay or else your hamburger icon wont show up
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    }

    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

}
```

### activity_dashboard.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.icici.iciciappathon.dashboard.DashboardActivity">

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/first"
                    layout="@layout/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
                    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/content_get_started"
                    layout="@layout/content_get_started" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                app:menu="@menu/drawer" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

### toolbar.xml

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/titleToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/all_toolbar" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</merge>
```

### drawer.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/history"
            android:checked="false"
            android:title="@string/login_client_id" />

    </group>
</menu>
```

### BaseActivity.java

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppCompatTextView mAppCompatTextView;

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    private String accessToken;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // register device with firebase
        }

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public <T extends ViewDataBinding> T setContentView(Activity mActivity, int layoutResID) {
        T viewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(mActivity, layoutResID);
        getToolbar();
        return viewDataBinding;
    }

    /**
     * Show a progress dialog.
     *
     * @param msg
     */
    protected void showProgress(String msg) {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing())
            dismissProgress();

        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), msg);
    }

    /**
     * Show progress dialog.
     */
    protected void dismissProgress() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            mProgressDialog = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show a toast.
     *
     * @param msg the text to show
     */
    protected void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /**
     * Show a alert dialog.
     *
     * @param msg the text to show
     */
    protected void showAlert(String msg) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert));
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setMessage(msg)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                }).create().show();
    }

    /**
     * Show a alert dialog to check out bought items.
     *
     * @param msg the text to show
     */
    protected void showAlertAndStartActivity(final Context context, String msg, final Intent intent) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert));
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setMessage(msg)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        dialogInterface.dismiss();

                        // start check out activity for payment
                        startActivity(intent);
                        ((Activity) context).finish();

                    }
                }).create().show();
    }


    protected Toolbar getToolbar() {
        if (mToolbar == null) {
            mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

            if (mToolbar != null) {
                setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
            }
        }
        return mToolbar;
    }

    protected void showToolbar() {
        mToolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    protected void setToolbarText(String title) {
        AppCompatTextView toolbarTitle = (AppCompatTextView) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.titleToolbar);
        toolbarTitle.setText(title);
    }

    protected void hideToolbar() {
        mToolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    protected String getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }

    protected void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    protected boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(
                Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null &&
                cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

}
```

### styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ICICIAppathonButton</item>
</style>
```

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:name=".AppApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: Are you setting your `Toolbar` as the support `ActionBar`? Or just using it as is?

Comment: Are you using a `NoActionBar` theme? That is, do you have an `ActionBar` and a separate `Toolbar`? Or are you trying to use your `Toolbar` as a custom `ActionBar`?

Comment: Yeah, just saw it. OK, you either need to move the `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` call to after the `setContentView()` call, or use the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` constructor that takes your `Toolbar` as the third argument. If you go with the first option, you need to also override the `Activity`'s `onOptionsItemSelected()` method to make the toggle work. The `Toolbar` option is probably the easiest.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks can you please answer I will mark it accepted

Comment: Ah, cool. Actually, if you went with the `Toolbar` constructor option, you can just accept Akp's answer, if you like. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks a lot! It worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this line

```
mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.home_screen_open_drawer, R.string.home_screen_close_drawer)
```

with this

```
mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolBar,R.string.home_screen_open_drawer, R.string.home_screen_close_drawer)
```

Hope this will help!